# Unable to git pull/checkout new branch due to untracked file

Tags: git

I have a weird situation I neither understand nor am able to fix.

I have a folder I have set to ignore `classlog`. But when I try to checkout master, I get this:

> error: Untracked working tree file 'classlog/database.class.php' would be overwritten by merge.

I'm guessing its because someone else made changes to the file, but as its ignored, why does git care? I don't know what I need to do in order to make sure I keep the files preserved. Its not even in the repository, so its not like I have to `git rm --cached`.

Answer (score 0):

This means the file has been checked into the git repository (master branch). So when you checkout master, the file from the server will overwrite the local file. The 'ignore' setting only affects uploading, but does not affect downloading. GIT will make sure all files on server will be downloaded regardless of the 'ignore' setting.

You can do a `git clean -f` to remove local files not in sync with the git branch.

Comment: I checked my master repo in case, but the files aren't on there :-/ And I can't afford to lose the files; when you say clean removes files not in sync, is that removes from the repo or removes the files entirely?

Comment: "git clean -f" removes local files not committed to the local git (not requiring them to be committed to server). If the file is not on server, git should allow you to do pull/merge. Can you checkout the branch on another working directory and see what's in the repo?

Comment: I've looked the repo over locally as well as looking at the file listing on BitBucket.org, but neither of them shows the file in question. And if clean actually removes files, I can't use it. These files are necessary, just not part of the repo.

Comment: Can you please paste your commands and the error messages? That will help.

Comment: `git checkout master` | `error: Untracked working tree file 'classlog/database.class.php' would be overwritten by merge.`

Comment: git checkout master refers to the local 'master' branch. i am not sure if you have done 'git clone <remote>' or 'git init' before. but i think the immediate problem is the command does not refer to the remote branch. you might try 'git checkout origin/master' as a next step.

Comment: I've been using the repo for a few months now; master was in use for quite a while. We switched to a side branch for a bit, and are now moving back to master as the branches are being merged. Master exists locally; I just can't seem to switch back to it.

Comment: I see the problem now. The current directory has got local changes that are not tracked by git so it doesn't allow you to switch branch. There are two things to do: 1) do a "git stash" to save the local changes (they can be restored by "git stash pop"), 2) add all changes to a patch (git commit -A -m "All changes")

Comment: Again, if its ignored, why is it picking up the file? Why has it not complained about this file before now?

Comment: "ignore" cannot override the completeness of the repo. if something is already in a repo/branch, it cannot be ignored.

Comment: And as I said, its not in the repo... its no where in the either branch when I get a fresh clone, nor can I find it visually in the BitBucket interface... Unless there's another way for it to be in the repo I don't know about.

Comment: it is probably in the local 'master' branch of the local git repository. can you do a 'git whatchanged master' to see files in the local master branch?

Comment: Ah, ok, I see the file there, though I don't remember ever adding it there. What can I do to remove it?